# Why does my custom cell only highlight when the user removes their finger?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

I have created a custom UITableViewCell, and set the backgroundView with the following code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NormalImage"]];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HighlightedImage"]];

    // other layout stuff
}
```

This works fine except that, when the user selects a row, it does not highlight - it only highlights when the user *lifts off* their finger (so you briefly see it highlight before transitioning to the next view). If I remove the `self.selectedBackgroundView` line, so that there is the normal iOS blue cell highlight, it will highlight as soon as the cell is selected.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView when initializing your custom cell. According to [apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938), the selectedBackgroudView is used as the background when the cell is selected.

If you write those codes in -(void)layoutSubviews, when the cell is selected, or unselected, it will call -(void)layoutSubviews. Then, your backgroundView and selectedBackgroundview will be re-assigned to new UIView instances each time when the state of custom cell has been changed.

Comment: Setting the backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView in the init method doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in the custom table cell

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    if (highlighted) {
    self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HighlightedImage"]];

    } else {
    self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NormalImage"]];

    }
}
```